# Error while installing mongodb in AWS EKS cluster - "running PreBind plugin VolumeBinding: binding volumes: timed out > waiting for the condition"

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I tried to install mongodb in EKS cluster by following the given links.
(using mongodb-kubernetes-operator)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqeTT0NvRR4&t=1s

https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator

```
kubectl apply -f config/crd/bases/mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com_mongodbcommunity.yaml
kubectl get crd/mongodbcommunity.mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com

kubectl create ns mongo

kubectl apply -k config/rbac/ --namespace mongo


kubectl get role mongodb-kubernetes-operator --namespace mongo

kubectl get rolebinding mongodb-kubernetes-operator --namespace mongo

kubectl get serviceaccount mongodb-kubernetes-operator --namespace mongo

kubectl create -f config/manager/manager.yaml --namespace mongo

kubectl get pods --namespace mongo
```

```bash
kubectl apply -f config/samples/mongodb.com_v1_mongodbcommunity_cr.yaml --namespace mongo
kubectl get pods -n mongo
```

When checked

```bash
kubectl get pods -n mongo
```

`example-mongodb-0` pod is in pending state for very long time.

Upon describing the pod got the following error,

> "running PreBind plugin "VolumeBinding": binding volumes: timed out
> waiting for the condition".

Answer (score 12):

I have contacted AWS support team regarding this issue and got the following response.

> From your correspondence, I understand that you are facing issues
> while creating the mongodb pods in your EKS cluster, and after
> creating the pod, your pod is going to pending status.
>
> Please let me know if I misunderstood your query. Thanks for sharing
> the GitHub repository URL using the same. I put some effort into
> replicating the same issue on my side, and thankfully I was able to
> replicate the issue.
>
> Further investigation into my pending pod problem I ran the following
> describe command on my cluster,
>
> "kubectl describe pod <pending_pod_name>"
>
> After several minutes, I found the following line in the "event"
> part of my output.
>
> "running PreBind plugin "VolumeBinding": binding volumes: timed out
> waiting for the condition".
>
> On further investigation, I found that the mongodb pod module that you
> are trying to deploy on your cluster is trying to create an EBS volume
> as a persistent volume, which is why I got the aforementioned error.
> We need the EBS CSI driver add-on installed in your cluster to create
> an EBS volume using EKS, and the above error usually occurs if the EBS
> CSI driver add-on is not present. Since this add-on is not installed
> by default while creating the cluster you need to install it via EKS
> console add-on tab.
>
> Or another possibility is that, even though the add-on is present, it
> won't have the required permission to create the EBS volume. So,
> before we even install the EBS CSI driver add-on to the cluster, we
> need to make sure that we have created the IAM role for attaching to
> the add-on. The same is referred to over here[1].
>
> In your case, you can check whether the EBS CSI driver is present by
> running the following command:
>
> "kubectl get pods -n kube-system"
>
> And look for pods with names like "ebs-csi-controller-xxxxxxx." If
> you find one, it means you've already installed the EBS CSI driver,
> and the problem could be with permissions.
>
> For that, you need to run the following command.
>
> "kubectl describe pod ebs-csi-controller-xxxxxxx -c csi-provisioner
> -n kube-system"
>
> This will give an output of the configuration of the driver pod. In
> that output, you need to check for an environment called
> "AWS_ROLE_ARN:" If that wasn't present in your output, this implies
> that you haven't provided the IAM OIDC provider role for the add-on.
> So you need to create that role in the IAM console, then remove the
> existing EBS CSI driver add-on from the EKS cluster console, and then
> again add the EBS CSI driver add-on with that role as "Service
> account role". More details for adding the EBS CSI driver add-on to
> the cluster are referred to here[3].
>
> If you already have the value for "AWS_ROLE_ARN" then you need to
> check for the configuration of the role by using this
> documentation[2].
>
> So, keeping the above things in mind, I have created the IAM OIDC
> provider role for the add-on. For that, you need to follow all the
> steps regarding how to create an IAM role for the add-on as referred
> to here[2].
>
> After creating the IAM OIDC provider role, I have installed the add-on
> via console by following the steps in this documentation[3] and for
> the service account role, I have selected the OIDC provider role that
> was created in the above step.
>
> After installing the add-on, I tried to delete the mogodb database pod
> by running the following command.
>
> "kubectl delete -f
> config/samples/mongodb.com_v1_mongodbcommunity_cr.yaml"
>
> Then run the following apply command to redeploy the pods.
>
> "kubectl apply -f
> config/samples/mongodb.com_v1_mongodbcommunity_cr.yaml"
>
> After I checked the pods, I could see that the mongodb database pod
> had come to running status.
>
> The above is the most common issue that might happen, if none of the
> above is your problem then please share a convenient time along with
> the timezone you're working in as well as contact number with country
> code so that we can connect over a call and have a screen sharing
> troubleshooting session.

## reference links:

[1] Amazon EBS CSI driver add-on : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-csi.html

[2] How to create IAM OIDC provider for EBS CSI driver add-on : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/csi-iam-role.html

[3] Managing the EBS CSI driver add-on : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-ebs-csi.html

## Working commands/steps

(Steps mentioned by support team)

1. Creation of EKS cluster
2. Go to the newly created EKS cluster in AWS console. In the **Overview** tab, copy the value of **OpenID Connect provider URL** and save the value in some place for future reference.
3. Go to *IAM -> Identity providers -> Add Provider*. Select *OpenID Connect* as the *provider type.*
4. Paste the copied url from step 2, in the *Provider URL* textbox and click *‘Get thumbprint’*. Set *Audience - sts.amazonaws.com* in the corresponding text box.
5. Click the *‘Add Provider’* button.
6. Create the required iam role. *IAM -> Roles -> Create Role*. In the *‘Select trusted entity’* section, choose *‘Web Identity’* . In *Identity provider* drop down, select the OIDC option that is created in step 5. Choose **Audience - sts.amazonaws.com** in the drop down. Click **‘Next’**
7. Search for *AmazonEBSCSIDriverPolicy* policy in the next window and click ‘Next’ and give name,description,tags for the role and click create role.
8. In the *Roles* section, search for the newly created role in step 7 and go inside that role. *Trust relationships -> Edit trust policy.*

> "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/385AA11111111116116:sub":
> "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa"

9. Update the above text with current oidc id and add it as new key-value in the *Statement[0] -> Condition -> StringEquals*. Refer the full json structure of this trusted relationship json data in the last.
10. After updating the text, click ‘Update Policy’
    Go to *EKS -> Clusters -> Newly created cluster in step 1*. Click *Add-ons* tab, *Add new.*
11. In the pop up choose Name as **Amazon EBS CSI Driver**. *Version* as latest. Choose Role as the *role created in step 7*. If the above role is not listed in drop down, reload the section using the reload button and click **Add**.
12. After some time, the new **Add on** will become active. Then run this `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` command and we should see csi pods as shown.

```
    ebs-csi-controller-68d49f84c8-sl7w6   6/6     Running   0          109s 
    ebs-csi-controller-68d49f84c8-w2k6r   6/6     Running   0         2m19s 
    ebs-csi-node-ldmsm                    3/3     Running   0        2m20s
```

Then run the commands given in the question.

Following dictionary is the **Trusted relationships** json for role

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::112345678900:oidc-provider/oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/Axxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/Axxxxxxxxxxxxx:sub": "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:ebs-csi-controller-sa",
                    "oidc.eks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/id/Axxxxxxxxxxxxx:aud": "sts.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. 
my `eksctl` version is `0.115.0-dev+2e9feac31.2022-10-24T17:17:37Z`
I created another cluster in the same account with eksctl version `0.105.0` and MongoDB works as expected.

I did try adding `Amazon EBS CSI Driver` to my cluster created by `eksctl` version `0.115.0` and still having same issue.

Comment: I created another cluster with `eksctl` version `0.116.0` and facing the same issue

Comment: in the first comment. the `eksctl` version which works fine is `0.105.0` and not `0.115.0`

Comment: I checked with `eksctl` version `0.114.0` and that also works as expected. 
It seems that there is a breaking change in version `0.115.0+` which causes this issue or maybe `MongoDB Operator` needs an update for this change?

Comment: do you think this is an issue with MongoDB or clusters created by eksctl ?

Comment: Not sure. But you can check with AWS Support team if you have Developer plan for your account. @ArthurKazemi