# Error while installing mongodb 6.0.1 in AWS EKS cluster using mongodb-kubernetes-operator

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have followed the steps using [mongodb kubernetes operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator). Installed mongodb in EKS using
[step 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqeTT0NvRR4&t=1s), mongo kubernetes operator, [other references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73871493/error-while-installing-mongodb-in-aws-eks-cluster-running-prebind-plugin-volu)

config/samples/mongodb.com_v1_mongodbcommunity_cr.yaml

Changed **version** "4.2.6" to "6.0.1"

```bash
kubectl apply -f config/samples/mongodb.com_v1_mongodbcommunity_cr.yaml --namespace mongo
```

Now mongodb pods are in running state.
But when i try to connect to the pod, i am getting following error.

```bash
check@myvm:~/mongodb-kubernetes-operator$ kubectl exec -it example-mongodb-0 -n mongo -- mongosh

Defaulted container "mongod" out of: mongod, mongodb-agent, mongod-posthook (init), mongodb-agent-readinessprobe (init)
Warning: Could not access file: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/data/db/.mongodb'
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6333275665e5468262a90792
Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.5.4
Using MongoDB:      6.0.1
Using Mongosh:      1.5.4

For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/


To help improve our products, anonymous usage data is collected and sent to MongoDB periodically (https://www.mongodb.com/legal/privacy-policy).
You can opt-out by running the disableTelemetry() command.

 
Error: Could not open history file.
REPL session history will not be persisted.
AssertionError: You must pass either an "anonymousId" or a "userId".
command terminated with exit code 1
```

But when i run with mongodb docker image in local, i am able to login.

```bash
sudo docker run -d --name localmongo -p 27017:27017 -v mongo-data:/data/db mongo:6.0.1
sudo docker ps
```

Get container id and go inside mongo shell

```bash
sudo docker exec -it e95c18af9deed2808 mongosh
```